# Can't give write permission to Group for Directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, ftp

I want all the Users in Specific Group to Access the Directory. Here is what I've done till now.

```
chown -R www-data:GROUP_NAME /var/www/DIRECTORY
chmod g+w /var/www/DIRECTORY
chmod o-r /var/www/DIRECTORY
chmod g+s /var/www/DIRECTORY
```

I've added User to group `GROUP_NAME` using following Command.

```
usermod -aG GROUP_NAME USER_NAME
```

Also, Here's the Command I've used to Create User.

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/DIRECTORY -s /bin/bash -p `openssl passwd PASSWORD` -U USER_NAME
```

After Doing all these, I can't see the Files in directory when I connect to Server through SSH nor I can verify anything using this Account.

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: While trying to verify using `sslforfree.com`, I am getting this error. `Permission or write error. Make sure the directory is correct and the user has write access to the directory.`.

Comment: And is it SSH or FTP?

Comment: It asks for FTP Information. I can connect through Filezilla and SSH too from my Computer. I can even Create/Delete files from SSH from my computer. But that site shows error.

Comment: I tried to login using FTP through `net2ftp.com` but It is showing error too! Here is what I got `Unable to connect to FTP server 139.59.42.186 on port 22.`

Comment: When I try to Delete some file using FileZilla, Status Gets Stuck at `Status: Deleting "/var/www/DIRECTORY/license.txt"`.